# How to display uploaded files in laravel backpack?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel Backpack. I have used column type **"upload_multiple"** to upload multiple files. Now I want to show the links to the uploaded files in setUpShowOpeartion().

What I have done so far;

```
 $this->crud->addColumn([
        'name' => "documents",
        'type' => 'upload_multiple',
        'entity' => 'documents',
        'attribute' => 'documents',
        'model' => 'App\Models\ChannelDocument',
        
    ]);
```

It displays like this:

[image]

If I use something like this:

```
   $this->crud->addColumn([
        'name' => "documents",
        'type' => 'select_multiple',
        'entity' => 'documents',
        'attribute' => 'documents',
        'model' => 'App\Models\ChannelDocument',
       
    ]);
```

Though it displays the links, but these are not clickable:
[image]

I tried to use wrapper property over the column as well:

```
 'wrapper' => [
            'href' => function ($crud, $column, $entry, $related_key) {
                return $column['text'];
            },
          ],
```

But it says, **Undefined index: text**. Unable to get column text.

Does anyone have better insights on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
        'name' => 'images',
        'label' => 'images',
        'type' => 'upload_multiple',
        'disk' => 's3',
        'wrapper' => [
            'element' => 'img',
            'src' => function ($crud, $column, $entry, $related_key) {return 
                $column['wrapper']['href'];
        }]
]);
```

You might need to add width & other things to show your image properly but this above code will do the job Tried & Tested.